# Call c# function when ajax timer (countdown) shows 0

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, timer

I have big problem in simple task... On asp.net page is Multiview with two views,

In first View I have ajax timer, which count seconds from 60 to 0. Time is showing on label, in updatepanel. I would to call my c# function which do some things and change active view in the end.

How can i do this ?

I tried to check in Timer_tick event, if seconds == 0, i calling function, but it isn't working.
I tried also Timer1.Enabled = false, but it isn't working too.

I think, that i must use Javascript, but how ? I don't know where and how... I don't know Javascript yet.

This is my Timer_Tick event (Time on label is displaying properly)

```
  protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test t = (Test)Session["SelectedTest"];

        if (t.Remaining.Minute == 0 && t.Remaining.Second == 0)
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
        else
        {
            t.Remaining= t.Remaining.AddSeconds(-1);
            Label7.Text = t.Remaining.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
```

and my DoSomething() function:

```
     public void DoSomething()
        {

// Doing a lot of things....

            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 3;
        }
```

Function Dosomething works properly, i have also button calling this function - it's working But i also want to call function if remaining seconds == 0.

Comment: Did you try with `if (t.Remaining.Minute <= 0 && t.Remaining.Second <= 0)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have tried this. After debugging I know, that my c# function DoSomething() is working - but finally, View is not changed. After calling DoSomething(), Timer Ticking again...

I found js function:

```
function stopTimer()
{
      var timer = $find("<%=Timer1.ClientID%>")
     timer._stopTimer();
}
```

But I don't know, where can I call it.

**Edit:** I saw, that my function DoSomething() is calling many times. If Timer shows 0, function is calling in every tick

**Edit2:** Noob-solution :)

1. Add second Timer, set Timer2.Interval = 9999999  (or other high)
2. In Timer1_Tick event:

   t.Remaining = t.Remaining.AddSeconds(-1);
               Label7.Text = t.Remaining.ToLongTimeString();

   ```
           if (t.Remaining.Minute == 0 && t.Remaining.Second == 1) Timer2.Interval = 1000;
   ```
3. Call c# function in Timer2_Tick

Reason: If Timer is trigger of UpdatePanel, You can't call a c# function from Tick event

**I know, that is better solution for do this (probably JavaScript), but my deadline is soon, so I must use it.